# Call JSON file using Tkinter filedialog failed

Tags: python, json, pandas, tkinter

I've created a Platform GUI to take measurements. I separate the GUI and Measurement files. I made all input values in a JSON file, so before taking measurements I have to load json first. When I run measurement the json file is unreadable or `NONE`. Here I show my two `.py` files.
`gui.py`

```
import customtkinter
from customtkinter import filedialog

from measurement import *

class Myapp(): 
    """
    The class used to set or create GUI styles
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = customtkinter.CTk()
        self.root.geometry('1050x600')
        self.root.title("APx Platform")
        
        # MEASUREMENT
        call = AcousticResponse()
        self.m1 = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.frame_2, text="Load JSON Script", font=("Ubuntu", 12), command=call.open_file)
        self.m1.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=(65, 65), pady=(5, 10))
        self.m1 = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.frame_2, text="Run JSON Script", font=("Ubuntu", 12),command=self.o_and_t)
        self.m1.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=(50, 50), pady=(5, 10))
        self.m1 = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.frame_2, text="Save Data", font=("Ubuntu", 12))
        self.m1.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=(50, 50), pady=(5, 10))
        
    def o_and_t(self):
        call = AcousticResponse()
        call.SignalPath()
        call.setupSNR()

app = Myapp()
app.root.mainloop()
```

And here is `measurement.py`

```
class AcousticResponse():
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.df = None
    
    def open_file(self): 
        """
        This function is to load the JSON file which is the values that will be used when 
        making measurements
        """
        filetypes = [("Json File", "*.json")] 
        filenames = fd.askopenfilename(title="Open File", filetypes=filetypes)
        self.df = pd.read_json(filenames)
        
    def SignalPath(self):
        if self.df == None:
            print("fail")
            return self.df
        
        df = self.df
        APx = APx500_Application()
        APx.Visible = True
        APx.SignalPathSetup.OutputConnector.Type = OutputConnectorType.AnalogBalanced
        APx.SignalPathSetup.InputConnector.Type = InputConnectorType.AnalogBalanced
        APx.SignalPathSetup.Measure = MeasurandType.Acoustic
        input1 = APx.SignalPathSetup.InputSettings(APxInputSelection.Input1)
        input1.Channels[0].Name = "Mic"
        input1.Channels[0].Sensitivity.Value = float(self.df["sensitivity_value_mic"][0])
    
    def setupSNR(self):
        APx = APx500_Application()
        APx.AddMeasurement("Signal Path1", MeasurementType.AcousticResponse)
        APx.AcousticResponse.SweepType = FastFrequencyResponseSweepType.FastSweep
        APx.AcousticResponse.GeneratorWithPilot.Frequencies.Start.Value = float(df["frequency_start_value"][0])
```

I want the value input in the json file to be read in all functions

Comment: It is not clear what your problem is. You have read the JSON file to instance variable `self.df` which should be accessible in other class methods.

Comment: After I load the json file, it turns out that the file is `None`

Comment: Do you mean that `self.df` is `None`?

Comment: yess, `self.df` is `None`

Comment: As @hrungnir says in the answer, you have created another instance of `AcousticResponse()` and does not call its `open_file()`, so `self.df` is `None`.  Remove `call = AcousticResponse()` inside `o_and_t()`.  It is better to check whether `self.df` is `None` before executing other functions.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it is because your call = AcousticResponse() in o_and_t has re-init that AcousticResponse().df to None

I don't have much good idea here, but myself might do like this?

```
class Myapp():
    ...
        self.filenames = None

        # MEASUREMENT
        self.m1 = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.frame_2, text="Load JSON Script", font=("Ubuntu", 12), command=lambda: self.open_file())
        self.m1.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=(65, 65), pady=(5, 10))
        self.m2 = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.frame_2, text="Run JSON Script", font=("Ubuntu", 12),command=lambda: self.o_and_t(self.filenames))
    ...

    def open_file(self): 
        filetypes = [("Json File", "*.json")]
        self.filenames = fd.askopenfilename(title="Open File", filetypes=filetypes)

    def o_and_t(self, filenames):
        call = AcousticResponse()
        call.SignalPath(filenames)
...

class AcousticResponse():
...
    def SignalPath(self, filenames):
        self.df = pd.read_json(filenames)
        if self.df == None:
...
```

Comment: Is there another way to call it?